# Shopify API - What is correct way to charge merchant for paid application?

Tags: php, python-2.7, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-activemerchant

I am working on Shopify API to make application [shopify_python_api](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api), Application required taking charges recurring charges after 14 days trial period.
To make this work, after installation steps redirect app url to `create_charge` where i used

```
charge = shopify.RecurringApplicationCharge({
       'name': "tested 123123 123",
       'return_url': return_url,
       'test': True,
       'price': 0.02,
   })
charge.save()
pprint.pprint(charge)
```

as response i get `recurring_application_charge(4182835270)`, as per Rest-Api [document](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/app-store/charging-for-your-app/guides/implement-billing-model#implement-the-recurringapplicationcharge-resource) it should be json as response with `decorated_return_url` and `confirmation_url`.

what is the correct way to charge a merchant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're getting an object in return as per my understanding. There are to_dict(), to_json() etc. methods available with this object.

Converting to dict:

```
c = charge.to_dict()
print c
```

If you want to see all methods available

```
print dir(charge)
```

Comment: i am using pprint. so, i though it opens up any Object and related methods.  thanks for clearing concept.